# Add html element 'h1' in html element 'a' with php

Tags: php

I have the following html string in php

```
$html='<div style="display:block; float:left; width:40px;">&nbsp;</div><a href="http://cosa.gr/index.php?cPath=15" class="headerNavigation">text</a>';
```

and I need to add an 'h1' html element in the a element were the string text is in an programmatical way.
The bellow code shows the result I need.

```
$html='<div style="display:block; float:left; width:40px;">&nbsp;</div><a href="http://cosa.gr/index.php?cPath=15" class="headerNavigation"><h1>text</h1></a>';
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You just answered yourself, didn't you?

Comment: its php and i need a function to do this, come on :S

Comment: Now, you didn't mention this earlier, did you?

Comment: well its php m8, do you think that I would ask to do this by hand? :S Dont act like a compiler

Comment: You have no idea what kind of questions people ask. How am I supposed to know what you know and what you dont?

Comment: your still human, and if your are tired you can always go out. I insist don't act like a compiler

Comment: If someone posts a question, even if its tagged only in php and contain html in the question. first answer is 'jQuery?'. Hail jQuery... ;-)

Comment: true but I think that Google wont notice that I converted the element after ready state, since the spider doesnt read javascript. Thats why I need the element to be converted in server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `heading` tag into the last `anchor` tag:

```
$start = strrpos(substr($html,0,strrpos($html,"</a>")),">"); 
$html = substr_replace($html, "<h1>", $start+1,0);
$html = str_replace("</a>","</h1></a>",$html);
```

Comment: the only thing is that I get this charachter � in some conversions, you know why this is happening?

Comment: Can you give an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
$html = '<div style="display:block; float:left; width:40px;">&nbsp;</div><a href="http://cosa.gr/index.php?cPath=15" class="headerNavigation">text</a>';
$html = preg_replace('|class="headerNavigation">(.+?)</a>|', 'class="headerNavigation"><h1>$1</h1></a>' ,$html);
print_r($html);
```

Comment: could you update the code with some examples, so that I can provide you a general regex?

Comment: well the html code is actually the same the only thing that changes each time is the text because it represents a product name, and because those names are greek, I actually replaced it with a 'text'. You may think that each time all the code is the same the only thing that changes it the string text. It could be blabla bla, it could be lalala, it could be anything

Answer (score 0):

a) modify the code, that an h1-Tag is usually included

b) Replace the Link-Text with an Regex:

```
$oldstring = "... dour data without h1 ...";
$text = "... the Link-Text ...";
$newstring = preg_replace("/" . preg_quote($text) . "/", "<h1>" . $text . "</h1>", $oldstring);
echo $newstring;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need this? the simplest way.

```
$html='<div style="display:block; float:left; width:40px;">&nbsp;</div><a href="http://cosa.gr/index.php?cPath=15" class="headerNavigation">text</a>';

function inserth1($str) {
   $str = str_replace('class="headerNavigation">','class="headerNavigation"><h1>', $str);
   $str = str_replace('</a>','</h1></a>', $str);
   return $str;
}

echo inserth1($html);
```